# Authorization in ASP .NET Core Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am unable to implement policy-based authorization in ASP .NET Core for an action on a razor page.

I read through [this comprehensive document on authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and used its examples as guidence.

Razor page action code:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCreateAsync(string id)
```

Code in service configuration:

```
_ = services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("test", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            false));
});
```

I expect that if I call the action or endpoint service, e.g.

```
GET /Account?handler=Create
```

then the request will be denied with a 403 status response because the "test" policy states that everyone is unauthorized. However, in actual practice, the action is successfully called.

Comment: Can you show your Configure method in Startup?

Comment: You also need to use `UseAuthentication()` middleware for these authorization policies to actually matter.

Comment: Have you added UseAuthentication() middleware

Comment: Yes. I have added authentication middleware.

Comment: Updated document at https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/pull/18949/files

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Razor Pages doesn't support `[Authorize]` at the *handler* level. i.e. You can only authorise a page *as a whole*, on the `PageModel` itself, as noted in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?#apply-policies-to-razor-pages):

> Policies can ***not*** be applied at the Razor Page handler level, they must be applied to the Page.

If authorising the page as a whole isn't a workable solution, you might need to move your `OnGetCreateAsync` handler into a controller/action pair, which can be attributed with `[Authorize]` accordingly.

There's also a related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6301) in the docs for this:

> The `[Authorize]` filter attribute has been supported since 2.0 in Razor Pages, but note that it works at the page model *class* level

If you need a better workaround, see [akbar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100646/2630078) and [Jim Yabro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64858798/2630078).

Answer (score 6):

Another solution for it is to check authentication by if clause.like this:

```
if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      return Redirect("/Front/Index");
    }
```

and you can check `roles` in it too by finding role:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend following Razor Pages authorization conventions in ASP.NET Core that looks like this:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Contact");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Private");
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Private/PublicPage");
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Private/PublicPages");
});
```

In your case with policy `test` it would look like this:

```
options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account", "test");
```

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Authorize attribute is supported but only on `PageModel` like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace PageFilter.Pages
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ModelWithAuthFilterModel : PageModel
    {
        public IActionResult OnGet() => Page();
    }
}
```

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorize-filter-attribute

Comment: can I set a pattern route there like in mvc? or its not possible?

Comment: @ajgo Not sure but the documentation sets it per per page or folder.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `AuthorizeAttribute` since it's unsupported.

Instead, once you have configured your policies in `Startup.cs`, you will be able to check those policies from within the page handlers.

1. Inject `IAuthorizationService` into your page model constructor
2. Call `AuthorizeAsync()` from within the handler.
3. Run a conditional check on the result's `.Succeeded` property.
4. If `.Succeeded` is false, return a `Forbid()` result.

This has nearly the same result as the `[Authorize(Policy=...)]` but executes later in the page lifecycle.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
// ...

public class TestPageModel : PageModel {
    readonly IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService;

    public TestPageModel(IAuthorizationService authorizationService) {
        AuthorizationService= authorizationService;
    }

    // Everyone can see this handler.
    public void OnGet() { }

    // Everyone can access this handler, but will be rejected after the check.
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() {
        
        // This is your policy you've defined in Startup.cs
        var policyCheck = await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "test");

        // Check the result, and return a forbid result to the user if failed.
        if (!policyCheck.Succeeded) {
            return Forbid();
        }

        // ...

        return Page(); // Or RedirectToPage etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my workaround using [Permission-based Authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://www.zehntec.com/blog/permission-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/) :

```
    [Authorize(Permissions.PageX.AddParameter)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddParameterAsync(uint id, string key, string value)
    {
        if (!this.ArePermissionsValid()) return Forbid();
        /// ...
    }

    public static class PageExtensions
    {
    
        public static bool ArePermissionsValid(this PageModel page)
        {
            try
            {
                var authorizeAttribute = new StackTrace().GetFrames().FirstOrDefault(x =>  x.GetMethod().Name.StartsWith("On")).GetMethod().GetCustomAttribute<AuthorizeAttribute>();
                if (authorizeAttribute == null) return true;
                var hasPermissions = page.User.Claims.Any(x => x.Type.Equals("permission") && x.Value.Equals(authorizeAttribute.Policy));
                return hasPermissions;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error($"${nameof(PageExtensions)}.{nameof(ArePermissionsValid)} | {e.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```