# Assigning IPrincipal to GenericPrincipal based on an API jwt that was returned

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, claims-based-identity

I am trying to assign a JWT to an Identity, essentially.  Since IIdentity is part of IPrincipal, I could do both, right?

The goal is to hook to the API, get a JWT to secure the API calls, and then secure the website pages based on the user's roles.

The API is built, the login takes place, the JWT is returned and parsed successfully...

Trying to assign the IPrincipal is WAY harder than it should be, in my opinion.

I've employed a generic like this:

`public class UserIdentityService : IUserIdentityService, IPrincipal, IIdentity`
`{`
`...`
`public void AssignUserContent(string UserName, List<Claim> claims)`
`{`
`GenericIdentity genericIdentity = new GenericIdentity(UserName);`
`claims.ForEach(f => genericIdentity.AddClaim(f));`

```
        'GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(genericIdentity, (string.Join(',', claims)).Split(','));

        IIdentity identity = genericIdentity;
        IPrincipal principal = genericPrincipal;

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = genericPrincipal;

        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User = genericPrincipal;
    }`
```

...
`IIdentity? IPrincipal.Identity => UserIdentityClaimsPrincipal();`

```
    string? IIdentity.AuthenticationType => "Bearer";

    bool IIdentity.IsAuthenticated => GetUserAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

    string? IIdentity.Name => GetFullName();`
```

...

There are a series of methods that originate from the implementation of IIdentity and IPrincipal.

For the service, I have both the IPrincipal and IIdentity pointed to the same class, as outlined above...in the program

`builder.Services.AddTransient<IPrincipal, UserIdentityService>(); builder.Services.AddTransient<IIdentity, UserIdentityService>();`

I can hit the login page, login successfully, call the method AssignUserContent(dot dot dot) and everything seems copacetic.  The User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is correctly populated with true, the 57 Claims exist, etc., in the login page debugging that authenticates me with a JWT from the API  (this site is consuming the API).  The API sees me as authenticated because I can reach every class with the Authorize adorner, successfully.

The web portion, which consumes the API, is the one that I am shaking my head over.  There are many other ways to achieve what I am doing, but why roll my own when I can leverage the MS solution with Identity?

This should be easy, right?  I am either missing something trivial, or this is entirely too complicated?

I've tried creating different classes to hold the reference to the IIdentity and IPrincipal and injecting them into the DI, like above with both being leveraged so I can have a one stop shop...

If I migrate the code into the website login controller, I can debug and see that everything is populated successfully:

`GenericIdentity genericIdentity = new GenericIdentity(UserName);`
`claims.ForEach(f => genericIdentity.AddClaim(f));`

```
        GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(genericIdentity, (string.Join(',', claims)).Split(','));

        IIdentity identity = genericIdentity;
        IPrincipal principal = genericPrincipal;

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = genericPrincipal;

        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User = genericPrincipal;`
```

from a custom class

`public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
commented out, IPrincipal
commented out, IIdentity
, ICustomAuthenticationStateProvider
{

```
    private IHttpContextAccessor                _httpContext;

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext                            = httpContext       ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));
    }`
```

I can pull back from this method:

```
    `public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var tkn = _httpContext.HttpContext?.Session.GetString("token");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tkn))
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseTokenClaims(tkn), "jwt")));

        }

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));

    }`
```

and in the view I can **successfully** do this in the Razor view.cshtml:

`@inject Web.Services.User.IUserIdentityService _userIdentity`

```
                `@if (_userIdentity.GetUserAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                {
                   <div>"You are in this role: Administrator";</div>
                }`
```

I can see that the
`_userIdentity.GetUserAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User` 
is populated for everything that should be if I reference it in another controller, any controller.

but how do I get that result to be assigned to the IIdentity and IPrincipal!?

I've tried to add the GenericIdentity and make that assignment, as well as GenericPrincipal and make that assignment...nothing works.  It seems to work, but every page that I try to access after the original assignment, to the Identity object only, fails.

`_userIdentity.GetUserAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User`
always gives me the right answer, but I cannot apply that to the Authorize adorner on the pages of the website, and the Authorize (Roles: etc.) for each portion of the website.

How can I control that?  Assign the .NET 6 IIdentity/IPrincipal objects to the custom one which is derived from a JWT.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the existing 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer' implementation?

Comment: I was unable to make that work with the Authorize adorner on the website.  Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I don't know what you're missing without seeing what you tried. The first thing that comes to mind is whether the claim in your JWT uses the name `role` or `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`. I would highly recommend using the existing implementation and understanding why it's not working, rather than rolling your own. You'll find it much easier to maintain and there's less chance of implementing it wrong and introducing a security risk

Comment: And I will be able to add the [Authorize] adorner on the website, not the API, correct?

Comment: If you're using Razor pages, you would normally use the `<AuthorizeView>` component to conditionally render sections of the page based on the user's role

Comment: If you want to limit access to the whole page, [see this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68759541/2363967)